# Toggle class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a FAQ, behind every question there is a '+' icon, after clicking on it the answer appears and the icon changes to a '-' icon. The problem is that when you click on the next question the icon of the previous question doesn't toggle back to the original/previous/other icon.

**See example:**

https://codepen.io/pixelarchitect/pen/eXLEJV

HTML

```
<div class="faq">
<div class="question">Q <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>
<span class="answer">A</span>
</div>

<div class="faq">
<div class="question">Q <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>
<span class="answer">A</span>
</div>

<div class="faq">
<div class="question">Q <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>
<span class="answer">A</span>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.faq span').hide();

$('.faq div.question').click(function(e){

  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this).parent().find('span');
  $(".faq span").not($this).hide();
  $this.toggle();

  $(this).find('svg').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus')

});
```

I'm using jQuery and the free version of FontAwesome for this example.

Comment: Please include _all_ code necessary for recreating the problem within the question itself.  See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Just added the missing HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the font-awesome svgs and use `.addClass("fa-plus").removeClass("fa-minus")` - excluding the current div's parent:

```js
$('.faq span').hide();

$('.faq div.question').click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var div = $(this).parent();
  var $this = div.find('span');
  $(".faq span").not($this).hide();
  $(".faq").not(div).find("svg")
    .addClass("fa-plus")
    .removeClass("fa-minus");
  $this.toggle();

  $(this).find('svg').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus')

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/js/all.js"></script>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">Q <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>
  <span class="answer">A</span>
</div>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">Q <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>
  <span class="answer">A</span>
</div>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">Q <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>
  <span class="answer">A</span>
</div>
```

Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EMevMz

Answer (score 2):

Using a quite similar logic as your show/hide, you can restore all `svg` back to plus signs, except the clicked one... See below.

```js
$('.faq span').hide();

$('.faq div.question').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    
    var $this = $(this).parent().find('span');
    $(".faq span").not($this).hide();
    $this.toggle();
    
    // This line turns all fa-minus into fa-plus except the clicked one
    $('.faq svg').not($(this).find('svg')).removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
    
    $(this).find('svg').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/js/all.js"></script>

<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">Q <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>
  <span class="answer">A</span>
</div>

<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">Q <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>
  <span class="answer">A</span>
</div>

<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">Q <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>
  <span class="answer">A</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, both your and @freedomn-m 's answers work, I checked his one as answered because im using his solution (identical to yours but I can only accept one answer)

Comment: There is a subtle difference, but would be micro-optimisation to recommend one over the other; other than `$('svg')` which would change all the font-awesome icons across your whole page :) (ok for the demo, easily changeable to `$('faq svg')`